# Instantiate all classes from a directory in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, require

I got a series of classes in typescript files in a directory and I'd like to get them all into a list. Here's what I done so far:

Example of class I like to instantiate:

```
export class MyClass1 {
    constructor() { this.test = "a test" }
    ...
}
```

And here's the function that should load them all:

```
public getMyClasses() {
    let MyClasses = [];

    //this.getMyClassFiles() return all the filenames of the classes in the directory
    for (const myClassFile of this.getMyClassFiles()) {
        const myClass = require(`${this.myClassFileRequirePath}/${myClassFile}`);

        MyClasses.push(new myClass());
    }
    return MyClasses;
}
```

Now, if I try to instantiate the class I just required,I get an error saying that "MyClass is not a constructor". How do I fix it?

Comment: is this a NodeJs app or webapp?

Comment: NodeJS app. To be precise, it's a Discord bot using Discord.JS.

Comment: Nope. That's what this.getMyClassFiles() do. I require each of the files, but I need to instantiate the class before adding it in the array MyClasses.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around it. I need to export the class in a object.

```js
class MyClass1 {
    constructor() { this.test = "a test" }
    ...
}

module.exports = {outClass: MyClass1}
```

And then get it from the object.

```js
public getMyClasses() {
    let MyClasses = [];

    //this.getMyClassFiles() return all the filenames of the classes in the directory
    for (const myClassFile of this.getMyClassFiles()) {
        const myClass = require(`${this.myClassFileRequirePath}/${myClassFile}`);

        MyClasses.push(new myClass.outClass());
    }
    return MyClasses;
}
```